# Some tools are not mentioned on the moderator tools information page, please add them

Tags: feature-request, privileges, 10k-tools

The only site on which I can view the 10k tools page is RPG.SE, so I'll be quoting and providing links and screenshots from there.

The [Moderator Tools informational page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) states:

> **Access moderator tools**
> You now have access to various lists and statistical reports, giving you a broad overview of activity on the site:
>
> - Posts with extreme votes
> - Posts with the most comments/views/edits
> - Recently protected questions
> - Recently closed/reopened questions
> - Recently migrated questions
> - Recently deleted/undeleted posts
> - Questions with pending close/reopen votes
> - Posts with pending delete/undelete votes
> - New answers to old questions
> - Suggested edit stats
> - The full history of reviews by all users in any /review queue

However, missing from this list are three tools:

1. [anonymous and low rep post feedback](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback)
2. [question close stats](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats)
3. [protected questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tools/protected-questions)

As far as I can find, you gain access to all of these at 10k reputation, but the 10k informational page does not mention any of them. Instead, they appear at the bottom of any tools page (the one below also includes "site analytics" though that link does not appear for those with a reputation between 10k and 25k):

[image: A screenshot of the list of links found at the bottom of any Tools page]

Please mention these tools on the informational page so that people can know that they have gained access to them.